# Xcode error 0xC011 when downloading container

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to get app data from my iPad onto my Mac.  In the past I have been able to do this in Xcode by going "Window > Devices" then selecting the app, pressing the gear button, and selecting "Download container..." The app I am trying to do this with has a lot of images (~750), and in Xcode 7 I get this error:

[image]

The app data it downloads is missing ~100 images.  This error happens every time.  I have looked on my computer and I have not been able to find the "com.apple.xbs" directory that it mentions.

Does anyone know where I can find this directory, or a solution to this error, or an alternate way I can get app data?

Comment: Same problem here with an app that has only documents inside. Dont know why...